# `InvalidArgumentError` occurred when attempted to fit the CNN model in keras?

Tags: python, error-handling, keras

I built convolutional models for the task of sentence classification and model compilation was successful. However, when I attempt to fit model with my training/validation dataset, I got strange `invalid argument error` down below:

> ```
> InvalidArgumentError: indices[120,1] = 77 is not in [0, 70)
>    [[{{node embedding_32/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT,
> ```
>
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_32/embeddings/read,
>   embedding_32/Cast, embedding_32/embedding_lookup/axis)]]

here is the architecture of my model (screenshot):

[image]

I am new to `keras` framework and don't understand this error much. Point is model compilation is succeeded but model fitting threw above error.

Any way to debug this error? can anyone point me out how to make this works? any idea?

Comment: The error just says that the embedding expects indices in the range [0, 69] with 69 inclusive, but it saw an index with value 77. This is related to the vocabulary size (the first parameter in your Embedding).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I tried what you suggested to me, but now I got this error: `InvalidArgumentError: indices[12,0] = 328 is not in [0, 70)
  [[{{node embedding_15/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_15/embeddings/read, embedding_15/Cast, embedding_15/embedding_lookup/axis)]]`. how can I fix this? any idea?

Comment: I haven't suggested any possible solution, this is more of a conceptual problem than a programming one. The problem is that the vocabulary doesn't match with the indices in your input data.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro what should I do? could you point me out what to do or possible concrete solution to overcome this problem? Thank you

Comment: I already did, I told you to check that the vocabulary is appropriate for the training and testing sets, and that no index is bigger than the size of the vocabulary. I am not an NLP expert and you didn't provide any more information (like more code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that your input index 77 is larger than 69 the maximum your `Embedding` expects. You have two options:

- Either increase the embedding input dimension to 78 or really to `np.max(x_train)+1` or
- Double check your `x_train` to ensure the indices are within the range [0,70).

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/):

> **input_dim:** int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.

Comment: I tried your solution but still same error. To let you understand my implementation, I created [gist code for this problem](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/f070a551de172404445cb807446c06aa) to see my implementation. could you take a look my gist and why your solution doesn't work also? Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on how you pre-process your sents `x_train` data. Your `alphabet_size` needs to be correct basically.