# How to reset indices of numpy.ndarray into desired index range?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

when I tried to fit keras models with customized textual data, I had index error. I reasoned that I have to change indices of my training dataset into certain index range. To do so, I tried `numpy.squeeze` and `numpy.reshape` but I didn't get the desired output.

**earlier post**:

I raised my question in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111916/invalidargumenterror-occurred-when-attempted-to-fit-the-cnn-model-in-keras/55112062?noredirect=1#comment96968152_55112062) and I realize that I have to reset the index of numpy array into the desired index range.

Here is how my original training dataset stored in `numpy`:

```
array([[   7, 6968, 1141, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [2091,  964,  866, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [ 127,  101, 3546, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       ...,
       [   7, 3056,  184, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [5040,   55,   56, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [ 259,  430, 1981, ...,    0,    0,    0]])
```

here is dimension info:

```
x_train.shape - > (10240, 100)
```

my goal is I want to reset indices of above `numpy` array into `(10240, 70)` to make my model run successful. How can I make this happen for deep learning model configuration? any way to reset indices of training dataset in `numpy` array in desired index range? any idea?

Comment: What "indices" do you think are associated with an array?

Comment: I don't know what 'reset indices' means.  It's not a common array or numpy operation.  I don't know about `keras`

Comment: You have a more conceptual misunderstanding of what the problem is, from the previous question the problem is that your training vocabulary and your testing one have different lengths, you have to fix that somehow, but its not a programming problem, you need to think why they are different and how to make them the same. Its not a magic call to some python or keras function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `numpy.squeeze` and `numpy.reshape` preserve the number of elements. The only way to turn a numpy array of shape `(10240, 100)` into that of shape `(10240, 70)` is by getting rid of elements, through [numpy slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html), and then reshaping (using `reshape` or `squeeze`) if necessary.

Note that blindly slicing your dataset will most likely ruin it. It may be best to rework your ML model to use the original dataset or look into ways of doing dimensionality reduction.

Comment: your answer can't help me also, any better idea?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get from `(10240, 100)` to `(10240,70)` you can just do

```
x_train_new = x_train[:,:70]
```

and drop the 30 dimensions. You will lose the information in those 30 dimensions, but from the small example you posted it looks like they are 0 anyways.